# JS function: prototype overriding vs prototype extension

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Sometimes I see such JavaScript code:

```
funciton MyClass () {
    // some initialization
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    constructor: MyClass,

    // other functions
}
```

What is the benefit in overriding function's prototype vs just extending prototype like this:

```
function MyClass () {
    // some initialization
}

MyClass.prototype.doStuff = function () {
    // some code
}
```

In the first example (overriding prototype) we must in addition specify constructor manually, but in the second example constructor will point to the function automatically. It seems to me that the first example is a bit better, because we do not need to specify constructor manually

So why do some people use first way? Is there any advantage?

Thanks

Comment: i had the same doubt since a long time,but i assumed it as the same thing..i dunno..thx for asking.The question will help many other people

Answer (score 2):

The first example will erase any previous prototypes defined (if any). The second approach will leave them untouched (including the constructor reference) but the code mass can be larger if you have a lot of prototypes.

It’s worth noting that you don’t *have to* specify a constructor reference if you override the prototype object, it’s just for convenience and not used very often.

Other than that – the difference is just in the syntax and explaining why some people prefer the other way is IMO like explaining why some people prefer 2 or 4 indentation spaces in their code – **it’s just a coding style**.

Comment: But without specifying a constructor reference I would not be able to do something like this: `MyClass.prototype.constructor.call()` correct.

Comment: @kromol It’s exactly the same as `MyClass.call()` - calling the constructor reference is not more "correct"